# ASP.NET Web API Route not found with Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have an ASP.NET Web API project that contains multiple controllers. All controllers handle Models that exist in the database, but one. And this controller does not get his (one) Action resolved. Here is the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MobileStations")]
public class MobileStationsController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All clients</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName(nameof(GetMobileStationsAsync))]
    [Route("", Name = "GetMobileStations")]
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<MobileStation>> GetMobileStationsAsync()
    {
        var snmpConfig = CiscoWlcSnmpHelpers.ReadSnmpConfiguration();

        var clients = await CiscoWlcSnmpHelpers.GetAllClientsWithAllAccessPointsFromAllWirelessControllersAsync(snmpConfig);

        return clients;
    }
}
```

I use Attribute Routing in all Controllers, with the exact same usage. Here is the `Register` Method from WebApiConfig.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers the config
/// </summary>
/// <param name="config"></param>
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    // Attribute routing
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Conventional routing
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());

    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
}
```

I used the Route Debugger with this result. URL is `api/Mobilestations`:
[image: Route not found]

Excerpt of the Route selection table:
[image: Route not detected]

So he uses the default route. Why is my custom route not detected on only this controller? It's the only one that is not accessing the database to get information. There is no table MobileStation in the DAL and I don't want to put an empty table into my database, just to get it to work. What does the routing engine care about the database?

Comment: What URL are you trying to access the endpoint on?

Comment: oh yeah sure, I forgot. It's api/mobilestations (exactly what the routeprefix is saying). I updated my question with the URL @CraigH

Comment: Can attribute routing be applied to static methods?

Comment: I think Sunshine has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Oh what a blunder. Didn't even thought about it. A lesson to be careful with code analysis tools like StyleCop and their recommendations. Thank you @Sunshine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are not allowed to be static methods

> **Which methods on the controller are considered "actions"?** When
>   selecting an action, the framework only looks at ***public instance
>   methods on the controller***. Also, it excludes "special name" methods
>   (constructors, events, operator overloads, and so forth), and methods
>   inherited from the ApiController class.

Source : [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API: Action Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection)

Update action to be an instance method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MobileStations")]
public class MobileStationsController : ApiController {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All clients</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName(nameof(GetMobileStationsAsync))]
    [Route("", Name = "GetMobileStations")] //GET api/MobileStations
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MobileStation>> GetMobileStationsAsync() { ... }
}
```